# Perl script not updating when disk code changes are made

Tags: perl

I have a perl package called mypackage.pm (that i have on disk)

I have a script called test.pl

Inside my test.pl I have the following statement

```
use mypackage;
```

Now why, when I make changes inside mypackage, are those changes are NOT reflected when running my test.pl script?

Comment: If you mean whether changes in `mypackage.pm` get automatically loaded into a running `test.pl`, the answer is no. If you (re)start `test.pl` after saving changes to `mypackage.pm`, please show a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Most likely, you are not editing the file you think you want to edit.

Comment: @Corion you my friend, could not be on the money more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

When you start a Perl program, the perl compiler will read all the modules referenced in the program from disk, compile them and store the resulting opcode in memory. It will also remember which files it has already read (in `%INC`) so it does not read them again.

There is a difference to *when* those files are read, but they are likely not significant here. If you `use` a module, it will be loaded at compile time, as in when the program starts. If you `require` a module, that can be inside of conditionals, and the file will be read when that code is executed at run time. That might be while the program starts up, or way later, or even never. Perl then switches back to compile time for that file to compile it, and then returns to run time.

If you want to re-read a module that you use, you will typically have to restart your program.

---

Having said that, there are some black magic implementations that allow you to re-load a module that has changed on disk. Unless you are building a daemon with insane start-up time and high throughput there is probably no need to use that.

One of these modules is [Module::Reload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Reload). Its been around for a while and has recently seen some changes. Its See Also section points to further implementations, namely [Module::Reload::Selective](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Reload::Selective) and the [again](https://metacpan.org/pod/again) pragma.

I have used neither of these and can't say if they work or how.

Comment: When you say restart your program, I am just executing from command line inside a directory on linx i.e. sudo ./test.pl - what do I restart in this case? I am not using apache or anything I can restart, do I need to start a new terminal?

Comment: @Sim if your program end, and you start it again, it will load modules freshly from disk. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I am just really dumb... thanks for your help. I copied my scripts to another directory. When i edit mypackage.pm i was editing the copied one, however my script seemed to be referencing the original one, despite being in the same directory as the package i was editing.

Comment: @Sim it happens to the best of us :)